# saving mysql backup database using php with mkdir path

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

I have a database back up which I wanted to have a directory using mkdir then save the back-up file inside that new created directory. but I'm having trouble saving the backed up file inside that new created mkdir folder. Here is the saving code together with the creation of the mkdir :) thanks!

```html
//save file
 $date = date("Y-m-d");
    
    $dir = "new_folder_name";

    if( is_dir($dir) === false )
{
    mkdir($dir);
}
 
    $path = '/new_folder_name/';
   
    $handle = fopen($path.'db-backup-'.$date.'.sql','w+');
    fwrite($handle,$return);
    fclose($handle);
```

Comment: Do try and get out of the habit of cluttering up your code with needless things like `=== false`. Many functions are designed to return values that evaluate as logically true or false so that's redundant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that only the directory path setting is incorrect.
Please check the following codes. It works on my computer.

```
<?php
//save file
$date = date("Y-m-d");

$dir = "new_folder_name";

if( is_dir($dir) === false )
{
    mkdir($dir);
}

//Use this setting will help 
$path = 'new_folder_name\\';


$handle = fopen($path.'db-backup-'.$date.'.sql','w+');
fwrite($handle,"abc");
fclose($handle);
```